# Adding an active menu trail to the main ul, in the html.tpl.php?

Tags: routes

Is there an easy way to get the active menu trail in this nav ul? I don't really understand PHP yet, I'm still learning. I personally would have setup the menu in Drupal, not in the html.tpl.php.

```
 <ul>
  <? foreach($full_menu_items as $menu_item) : ?>
  <? if($menu_item['#original_link']['has_children'] == '1') : $belowMenu = $menu_item['#below'] ?>

  <li class="<? { echo "";  } ?>">
  <div><? echo $menu_item['#original_link']['link_title'] ?></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
       <? foreach($belowMenu as $sub_menu_item) : ?>
       <? if($sub_menu_item['#original_link']['link_path']): ?>
         <li><a href="<? echo $sub_menu_item['#original_link']['link_path']; ?>"><? echo $sub_menu_item['#original_link']['link_title']; ?></a></li>
       <? endif; ?>
       <? endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
   </li>
        <? else: ?>
   <? if($menu_item['#original_link']['link_path']): ?>
   <li><a href="<? echo $menu_item['#original_link']['link_path']; ?>"><? echo $menu_item['#original_link']['link_title']; ?></a></li>
   <? endif; ?>

   <? endif; ?>
   <? endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
      <?php 
            $tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-mobile-menu'); 
            menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
            print drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));

        ?>
```

So much easier / nicer. And editable in Drupal, not the tpl files.

Answer (score 0):

Use [menu_tree_page_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7) to get an array of the menu items. Set the trail accordingly there.

Example: http://brightplumbox.com/30Drupal7API/#/7/4

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! Quick question: what php tags do I need to put around that, and then 'print $tree' or something to display it? I'm very new to php code.